# Why is $nM$ equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i$?

Tags: magic-square

In [this](https://youtu.be/ZkVSRwFWjy0?t=154) video it is said that  $nM$ for a given magic square is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i$, and then the result is also used for magic hexagons.

Why does this have to be the case, both for squares and hexagons? I haven't found any answers or clues on the Internet.

Comment: In a magic square which uses the numbers $1,2,3,\dots$, there are $n^2$ total spaces in the square and so the total of *all* entries is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n^2}i=\frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$.  Meanwhile the sum for *an individual row* (*which is what I would have called the magic number, not the sum of all numbers*) is the overall total divided by the number of rows, i.e. $\frac{n(n^2+1)}{2}$

Comment: Could you let us know what "magic number"  means please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a magic square, you have an $n\times n=n^2$ square to fill in, using the numbers $1,2,\dots,n^2$ (one for each box). So if you added them all up, it's $1+2+\dots+n^2$, which you can write as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i$$.

Comment: So, the entries have to be consequitive integers starting with $1$ for something to be a magic polygon?

Comment: @AlexAdamov not necessarily, but those are the types of magic polygons that they are talking about in that video.  If you are looking at a different class of magic polygons, then of course the total of all numbers, or the total of a specific row, need not follow the same pattern as these.  For history, details, and variations of the magic square see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)